# "Один" as an equivalent of indefinite article

Tags: числительные

Even though, theoretically, there are no articles in Russian, can **один** sometimes work as the indefinite article?

At least I've seen "**одни**" ("a few ones") which is similar in usage to "unos" in Spanish - the plural of the indefinite article.

For example, *"Schopenhauer wrote a biography [not the only one] in Greek"*.

If I say "Шопенхауер написал биографию на греческом", there's no way to tell whether it was his single biography or one of many.

As such, is it OK to say "Шопенхауер написал **одну** биографию на греческом" to make clear that it was "a biography" rather than "the biography"?

Comment: "Шопенхауер написал одну биографию на греческом" would sound like "Schopenhauer wrote one of his biographies in Greek" (I don't know if it matches your intended meaning).

Comment: "one of his..." - that's right, that's what I was looking for! Спасибо!

Comment: @swrutra Please note, it's *"Шопенгауэр"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no such thing like articles in Russian, whether definite or indefinite. However, in some specific phrases it de-facto acts very similar to indefinite article.

Compare following two sentences:

> Этот анекдот мне рассказал один мужик.

and

> Этот анекдот мне рассказал мужик.

Both sentences are completely valid, however native speaker will perceive the second one as incomplete - it's implies that there's somebody very specific (`мужик`) but it's not clear who exactly. You can even hear something like `мне один мужик один анекдот рассказал`.

As a side-note - there's a theory which is backed up by a lot of data actually that this is exactly how indefinite articles evolve - [they usually are derived from numerals](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3596/origin-of-articles-in-european-languages/3621#3621).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, один is translated as "a/an", or "a certain" ([link](https://ru.pons.com/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4?q=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD&l=enru&in=ac_ru&lf=ru)).

> Шопенхауер написал одну биографию на греческом

(Shopenhauer is transliterated as Шопенгауэр.  "h" is often transliterated as "г".)

Here, `одну` as `a` is too easily confused with `одну` as `one`. It would be understood as "Shopenhauer wrote one biograhy on Greek" (rather than two or more).   `Один` as `a` is used in sentences where such confusion is unlikely, i. e. `мне это сказал один знакомый`, `я это прочитал в одной книге` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes (not too often), **один** really just adds the same sense of indefiniteness as articles a/an/un/uno/una/un' do.

> **Один** мой друг живёт в Канаде. (**A** friend of mine lives in Canada. /I
>   have **a** friend living in Canada./)

It's not about '*friend count*', it just prevents from false conclusions about '*my only friend / FFL*' which are possible in case один is omitted here (*Мой друг живёт в Канаде*).

As for your example, the word **один** is useful in a Russian translation, with the following word order:

> Шопенгауэр написал на греческом биографию **одного** человека.

It keeps the original's (Schopenhauer wrote a biography in Greek) measure of *indefiniteness* (no ideas if it was the only biography he wrote), while the literal version with direct replacement of the article (*Шопенгауэр написал **одну биографию** на греческом*) has an extra emphasis on *на греческом* and leaves unnecessary questions: was he a prolific biography writer who wrote one of those in Greek / was it just one / could it be an autobiography?

It is true that some forms of Spanish and Italian indefinite article even coincide with the word meaning '**one**' but in the function of *article* they just express *indefiniteness*, so **unos** doesn't mean '*ones*', it means **'some'** (items in plural). In English, a/an  tend to mean '*one of the specified kind*', not simply '*one*'.